# Organizing ordered results into labeled sections

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to properly place my returned results into  labeled sections - example of what i mean.

Controller:

```
public IEnumerable<Users> GetUserList(int? id, int? pageNumber)
        {
            if (!id.HasValue)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            int _pageNum = pageNumber.HasValue ? pageNumber.Value : 1;
            return new UserService().GetUsers(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum);
        }
```

View:

```
<div id="listView"  data-bind="template: { name: 'list', foreach: Users }">
            <section id="Images">
                <section id="users"></section>
            </section>
        </div>
```

knockout.js/jquery: **UPDATED**

```
  var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
// The ViewModel for the page
var viewModel = {
    Users: ko.observableArray([]),
    users: ko.observableArray([]),
    groups: ko.computed({
        read: function(){
            var groups = [];
            var groupLetter;
            for(var i = 0; i <letters.length; i++){
                viewModel.Users.groups[letters[i]].users([]);
            }
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.users(), function (user) {
                groupLetter = user.name()[0].toUpperCase();
                if (groups.indexOf(groupLetter) < 0) {
                    groups.push(groupLetter);
                }
                groups[groupLetter].users.push(user);
            });
            return groups.sort();
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    }),

};
for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    viewModel.users.groups[letters[i]] = { users: ko.observableArray([]) };
}
```

// The ViewModel for the page

```
var viewModel = {
    Users: ko.observableArray([]), //already a sorted list of users
    TotalRoster: null,
    CurrentPage: ko.observable(1),
    DataIsLoading: ko.observable(false),

};
```

So this returns in the view: 
Amanda
Bob
Frank
Kate
Tim

I would like to have this displayed in the view:

### A (Header)

Amanda

### B (Header)

Bob

### F (Header)

Frank

### K (Header)

Kate

### T (Header)

Tim

Mainly for a visual reference for viewers to see - it will show letter headers for the users that exist so if there are no users with a name that starts with S then there won't be a S header. Any help as to where i could look into or what this could be called i could read about that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the users by their name on client side as follow :

```
// assuming the array is sorted
var users = ['Amanda', 'Anna', 'Bob', 'Frank', 'Francois', 'Sam'];

var lastGroup = null;
var vm = {
    groups: []
};

ko.utils.arrayForEach(users, function (user) {
    // known group
    if (lastGroup && lastGroup.name == user[0]) {
        lastGroup.users.push(user);
    } else {            
        // unknown group
        lastGroup = {
            name :user[0], users : [user]
        };
        vm.groups.push(lastGroup);
    }
});



<div data-bind="foreach:groups">
    <span data-bind="text:name" style="font-weight: bold"></span>    
    <br/>
    <div data-bind="foreach:users">
        <span data-bind="text:$data"></span>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rvsfw/)

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that you're not going to be able to do this by just looping through the Users array in the binding.  Each iteration through will generate that templated html code provided for each of the User objects.

One approach I would consider is creating a dynamic array of groups that are based on the first letter of the User's name and attach these to the root observableArray object.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    self.users = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.users.groups = ko.computed({
        read: function(){
            var groups = [];
            var groupLetter;
            for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
                self.users.groups[letters[i]].users([]);
            }
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.users(), function (user) {
                groupLetter = user.name()[0].toUpperCase();
                if (groups.indexOf(groupLetter) < 0) {
                    groups.push(groupLetter);// not listed?  Add it
                }
                self.users.groups[groupLetter].users.push(user);// Add to the grouped users array
            });
            return groups.sort();
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        self.users.groups[letters[i]] = { users: ko.observableArray([]) };
    }
}
```

Now in your View:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.users.groups, as: '$group' }">
    <h3 data-bind="text: $group"></h3>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.users.groups[$group].users, as: '$user' }">
        <li data-bind="text: $user.name"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QChNw/)

*Note:  You'd only want to go this route if you had a need to update these names dynamically on the client side.  If this list were to remain static, it'd probably be best to go with Damien's answer.

Comment: Thanks i will go ahead and try both out. Also i updated my post with my viewModel for the page in where i call the Users for the foreach. Would i place what you have in your viewmodel into the viewmodel where i have `users:ko.observableArray([])` or would i create a separate viewmodel?

Comment: If you can help it, I would keep it all in one ViewModel.  In your case, you're defining a ViewModel in an object directly instead of a constructor function.  Which is fine, where I have `self.users.groups = ko.computed(...);`, you would add that after your ViewModel declaration and it would look like: `viewModel.Users.Groups = ko.computed(...);`  Just be wary of the case sensitivity.  You're using upper case where as I'm using camel case.  Also, where I have `self.` references, you would have `viewModel.` references.

Comment: So i went ahead and implemented your solution but when i run it - in the console i get an uncaught error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'A' of undefined and that references to the `for loop`

Comment: If you look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QChNw/), I bet that's happening on line 10.  It happens because `self.users.groups` isn't defined yet when the computed tries to do its first evaluation during the declaration.  The part you may have overlooked is on line 21.  This tells KO, hey don't evaluate this yet until something calls this computed.  This allows you to make a reference to the computed, within the computed, before it's declared.